# How to set the Content-Type for SVG files parsed by PHP

Tags: php, apache2, svg

I currently use the following Apache httpd conf:

```
<FilesMatch "\.svg$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Parsing the PHP scripts in my SVG files
- Serving my SVG files with the `image/svg+xml` MIME type

However, the `AddType` seems to be ignored now that I've set it to use the alternative handler for my SVG files. They're now served as `text/html`.

How can I make the httpd parse the PHP in my SVG files while preserving its `image/svg+xml` type?

I currently include a `header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");` call in my SVG file to solve this, although I'd rather have a global way of doing this instead of having to insert this into all of my SVG files.

- CentOS 6.5
- Apache 2.2.15
- PHP 5.3.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up setting the handler for SVG files to `application/x-httpd-php`, and used apache's `mod_headers` to pass the correct content-type header.

```
<Files "*.svg">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
  Header set Content-Type "image/svg+xml"
</Files>
```

This was solved when I found a nearly identical question at https://serverfault.com/questions/348439/how-to-fix-apache-content-type-for-php-parsed-css.

Comment: Just to add, this will only work on Apache 2.2.12+. The [very last line of the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) state, "Prior to 2.2.12, it was not possible to change the Content-Type header with this [`Header`] directive.". I was trying to get something similar to work on an old Apache 2.2.9 server and I've hit a wall!?

Answer (score 2):

The [Apache mod_mime documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) states that `SetHandler` overrides `AddType`:

> While mod_mime associates metadata with filename extensions, the core server provides directives that are used to associate all the files in a given container (e.g., `<Location>`, `<Directory>`, or `<Files>`) with particular metadata. These directives include `ForceType`, `SetHandler`, `SetInputFilter`, and `SetOutputFilter`. The core directives override any filename extension mappings defined in mod_mime.

You should be able to use [the header directive from mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) in .htaccess to make it work:

```
<FilesMatch "\.svg$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    Header set Content-Type "image/svg+xml"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to do as you suggested, but it kept serving it as `text/html`. Could this be because the PHP handler will overwrite this value?

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution.  I hadn't tested the ForceType myself.  It looks like your `Header set Content-Type "image/svg+xml"` is the correct solution.  I'll edit that into my answer as well.